# Gnuplot plotting with image using non-square datablocks

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have run into a strange problem.  Every time I try to plot "with image" using a non-square data file I get very unexpected results.  Nowhere in any of the sources I've read  mentioned anything about whether the domain needed to have the same dimensions.

For example, I have a file called `plate` which consists of many datablocks each with 4 tab-separated columns.  The second and third columns represent x and y coordinates respectively. The first datablock in `plate` goes like:

```
0       0       0       293
0       0       0.1     293
.       .       .       .
.       .       .       .
.       .       .       .
0       5       4.9     293
0       5       5       293
```

When I `plot "plate" index 0 using 2:3:4 with image` I get the expected result.  This works for every index and the result is a square heat map with the 4th column as the heat value.  I want to do the same with my file called `pipe`, which uses the same format except for different ranges on columns 2 and 3.

```
0       5       2.2     293
0       5       2.3     293
.       .       .       .
.       .       .       .
.       .       .       .
0       10      2.9     293
0       10      3       293
```

Currently, I get the following:

[image]

The output should show a solid horizontal bar adjacent to the square but instead it is distorted.

I have tried other non-square data files and the results were even different from the attached image.  One attempt basically doubled the image but kept it square, even when the data wasn't.

Below is a truncated sample of `pipe` for testing.

```
0       5       2.2     293
0       5       2.3     293
0       5       2.4     293
0       5       2.5     293
0       5       2.6     293
0       5       2.7     293
0       5       2.8     293
0       5       2.9     293
0       5       3       293
0       5.1     2.2     293
0       5.1     2.3     293
0       5.1     2.4     293
0       5.1     2.5     293
0       5.1     2.6     293
0       5.1     2.7     293
0       5.1     2.8     293
0       5.1     2.9     293
0       5.1     3       293
```

Comment: Could you please provide the complete data or at least a minimal set of data which shows this effect?

Comment: @theozh  Done, I get the same effect with this file when running ```plot "<file>" using 2:3:4 with image"

Answer (score 2):

Ok I stumbled upon a solution, but I don't really know why it is the case or how to avoid it using gnuplot instead of rewriting the entire data file.

In the case of non-square data the problem seems to be that the column to be read first in the `using` statement needs also to be the column that is iterated over first.

For data that goes

```
1       1       1
1       2       2
1       3       3
2       1       4
2       2       5
2       3       6
```

Plotting by `using 1:2:3 with image` will result in a parallelogram, but plotting with `using 2:1:3 with image` will plot with the proper dimensions.  However, in the latter case the desired x-axis will be plotted on the y and vice versa.  I also added sequential test points in the above data to see where each square is drawn.

Attached below are results from the test data listed above.

[image: plot "test" using 1:2:3 with image]

[image: plot "test" using 2:1:3 with image]